# NIC Bonding Problem

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, netplan, network-bonding

My infrastructure is like below:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server running on VirtualBox
- 2 NICs, enp0s3 and enp0s8, both attached to Bridged Adapter

My netplan file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: no
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp0s3
        - enp0s8
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: enp0s3
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
```

- Installed ifenslave package with `sudo apt install ifenslave`
- Loaded bonding module with `sudo modprobe bonding`

After applying netplan, the bond is created, it gets an IP address from DHCP, but it cannot
reach anywhere on the network, neither I can connect to it.

I guess I'm missing something very obvious, but I couldn't find it for hours.

I tried bypassing netplan and configuring directly on systemd-networkd, the reault is the same. So I believe Netplan has nothing to do with it.

So I can safely blame Networkd, because bonding worked with Debian and ifupdown on the same infrastructure.

Output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:6c:54:32:ea:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 08:00:27:4a:df:8f
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:6c:54:32:ea:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 08:00:27:72:1e:49
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:6c:54:32:ea:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.55/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 3579sec preferred_lft 3579sec
    inet6 fe80::986c:54ff:fe32:eaa5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.55 metric 100
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.1.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.55 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev bond0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.55 metric 100
192.168.1.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.55 metric 100
```

Comment: What does the output of `ip a` and `ip route` show?  What are some examples of trying to reach "anywhere on the network"?

Comment: Added to the question. By trying to reach to network, I simply tried to ping 192.168.1.1. Thanks.